# File path/name from InputStream

Tags: java, io, inputstream

How to obtain File Path/Name from an InputStream in Java ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It's not possible.** (not from the FileInputStream in the Java API). The `FileInputStream` constructor does not store this information in any field:

```
public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String name = (file != null ? file.getPath() : null);
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkRead(name);
    }
        if (name == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    fd = new FileDescriptor();
    open(name);
    }
```

Comment: This is no longer quite true.  The path is now stored, but still is not accessible.

Answer (score 10):

You can't because the `InputStream` might not have been a file or path.  You can implement your own `InputStream` that generates data on the fly

Answer (score 5):

Two important Object Oriented Design principles prevent you from doing what you're asking: abstraction and encapsulation.

- **Abstraction** is the process of defining a general concept that has only the details necessary for its use in a particular context (more details [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/230409/187751)). In this situation, the abstraction is `InputStream`, which is a general interface that can provide bytes, *regardless of the source of those bytes*. The abstraction of an `InputStream` has no concept of a file path; that's only relevant to particular implementations of `InputStream`.
- **Encapsulation** is the process of hiding implementation details of a class from consumers/users of that class. In this particular situation, `FileInputStream` encapsulates the details of the file it is reading from, because as an `InputStream` that information is not relevant to the usage. The `path` instance field is *encapsulated* and as such unavailable to users of the class.

Having said that, it *is* possible to access the `path` variable if you are willing to accept some important limitations. Basically, the gist is that you can check if the `InputStream` is, in fact, an instance of `FileInputStream` and, if so, use reflection to read the `path` instance field. I'll leave out the details of doing that access since it's easily discoverablein the `java.lang.Class` Java docs and online, and not really a generally good thing to do in most contexts. Since the question doesn't provide a context about why, it's hard to offer any more reasonable approaches.