# How to access a String in an InputStream object?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a tiny method attempting to return a Windows file path from an 
InputStream object. In the Eclipse Variables window, I can see the String I 
want in the field 'path', but can't seem to access and return it. (See image.)

```
static String getPathFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return  "abc";     // Compile error from:  is.in.path;
}                      //  "in cannot be resolved or is not a field"
```

Two questions: Should I be able to access everything I see in the Variables 
window? And two, how do I return String 'path' (if I can)?

[Eclipse Variables window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Yip.png)

[image]

Comment: As indicated by the answer to the duplicate question, it's not possible in general. However, there are ways around it if you are willing to accept some limitations.

Comment: I can't answer this question since it was closed, but I added my own detailed answer to the other: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36802489/639520

Answer (score 1):

Your input stream object is of type FileInputStream but represented as InputStream, that property is for FileInpuStream.

And no you can't access all variables in that window, it's showing you all private and public variables, you can only access public members and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is: no, you are not supposed to get a path from the InputStream. The variable you are seeing is supposedly private, and as for the in field, there is a protected in field in filtered streams based on FilterInputStream, I believe.