# AOSP file access controll - Android with Java Security Manager

Tags: java, android, android-source, access-control, securitymanager

I would like to implement a file access control in the Android framework. It has to be global - for each app. So each file call (for example open an image) should be checked by this controller.

I thought to place it in the [FileInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html) or [FileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) class. Both doesn't support direct access to the file path by them self: [FileDescriptor no path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285469/get-path-from-filedescriptor-in-java) and: [InputStream no path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501936/file-path-name-from-inputstream).
But, how it is mentioned in the other question, I will try to use a `WeakHashMap<FileDescriptor,File>` to store the relations and information about the called FileDescriptor/InputStream.

The Java Security Manager provides an authentication & access control api. 
My question is now, is it possible to use it (by using `checkRead(FileDescriptor fd)`) in the Android framework? I also want to have dynamic restriction-filter, for example time-dependent access to the files.

I can't find something about in combination so I didn't even know if it's implementable. Here ([Java and Android Security](https://www.slideshare.net/pragatiogal/from-java-to-android-a-security-analysis-22138061)) we can see only the separately advantages of them.

Comment: "I would like to implement an file access control in the Android framework" -- are you implementing a custom ROM?

Comment: Sorry, yes I do. I forgot to mention it. I downloaded the aosp-source code and build an image-file to run and test it for now with the emulator.

Comment: Enforcing file access at the Java level misses things that bypass Java, such as NDK libraries and `WebView`.

Comment: Oh I understand.... Does this mean I have to go deeper and edit the bionic library or do I have to go on kernel level to implement this access control? (Edit the read systemcall).

Comment: That is outside of my area of expertise, sorry.